# Is the following function measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $(Y,\Gamma,\nu)$ be a finite measure spaces. Consider the a measurable kernel $k:X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and suppose
$\int_{X}\int_{Y}|k(y,x)|d\mu(x)d\nu(y)$ exists.
Consider now $\phi(x,t)=\int_{B_{x,t}}|k(x,y)|d\nu(y)$, where $B_{x,t}=\{y\in Y||k(y,x)|>t\}$ and $t>0$. Suppose now $\alpha\geq 0$ is given. Is it true that
$s(x):=\inf_{t>0}\{t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}|\phi(x,t)=\alpha\}$ is a measurable function?

Comment: If $\varphi$ is measurable, then yes. I strongly suspect $\varphi$ is measurable but you need to decompose into components and maybe use approximation (on $k$) by simple functions.

Comment: I think $\Phi$ is measurable by considerung the function $s(x,y,t):=k(x,y)/t$, which is measurable. Then rewrite the integral, something like $\phi(x,t)=\int_{Y}|k(x,y)|\cdot\chi_{s^{-1}(1,\infty)}(x,y,t)d\nu(y)$??

Comment: @WilliamM., What is the argument that $s$ is measurable if $\phi$ is measurable?

Comment: $\phi$ is decreasing in $t$, so the infimum should be the same when $t$ is restricted to be rational.

Comment: @WilliamM., thank u, but the condition $\phi(x,t)=\alpha$ is eventually not fullfilled, if u take $t$ as rational. Do u have an idea ?

Comment: You are right, the equality $\phi=\alpha$ causes trouble. I have no idea how to account for that.